# Dynamic drop down from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two dropdowns, I want to fill (`deviceType`) from table `device_typt_table` with two columns `id`, `device_type` and (`brand`) from `brand_table` with `id, brand_name, device_type_id`.

I try to do that and print data with controller but can't print it in select box
but can print in my view Except select box

My view:

```
<html>
<head></head>
</body>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('speed/insert_to_db'); ?>


Branch: <input type="text"  name="branch" /><br/>
Business Unit: <input type="text"  name="buinessUnit" /><br/>

Device Type:<select name="deviceType" >
               <? foreach $devices as $post { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $post->device_type;?>"><?php echo $post->device_type;?></option>
                <? }?>
          </select><br/>
Brand:<select name="brand" >

          </select><br/>
Device Model: <input type="text"  name="deviceModel" /><br/>
SN: <input type="text"  name="SN" /><br/>
status: <input type="text"  name="status" /><br/>
department: <input type="text"  name="department" /><br/>
username: <input type="text"  name="username" /><br/>
notes: <input type="textarea"  name="notes" /><br/>
computername: <input type="text"  name="computerName" /><br/>
Save:<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="save" />


<?php foreach($devices as $post){?>
<?php echo $post->device_type;?>
<?php }?>  


<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Model:

```
    <?php
    class add_model extends CI_Model {

           public function insert_into_db(){
               $post=$this->input->post();
               $data=array('Branch'=>$post['branch'],'BusinessUnit'=>$post['buinessUnit'],'DeviceType'=>$post['deviceType'],'Brand'=>$post['brand'],'DeviceModel'=>$post['deviceModel'],'SN'=>$post['SN'],'Status'=>$post['status'],'Departmant'=>$post['department'],'UserName'=>$post['username'],'Notes'=>$post['notes'],'ComputerName'=>$post['computerName']);
               $this->db->insert('hardware_assets', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id(); // if using mysql

           }
    function all_devices()
    {
     $this->db->select("id,device_type");
      $this->db->from('device_type_table');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
    } 


     }
```

controller:

```
<?php

class Speed extends CI_Controller {

        function insert_to_db()
           {
               $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
              $this->load->library('form_validation');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch', 'Branch', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('buinessUnit', 'BuinessUnit', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('deviceType', 'DeviceType', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('brand', 'Brand', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('deviceModel', 'DeviceModel', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('SN', 'SN', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[hardware_assets.SN]');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('department', 'Department', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('notes', 'Notes', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('computerName', 'ComputerName', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            /*   

           */
$this->data['devices'] = $this->add_model->all_devices(); // calling Post model meAthod all_devices()
   $this->load->view('pages/home', $this->data);

           if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
             { 

             $this->load->view('pages/home');//loading success view     
         }
         else
         {
             $formSubmit = $this->input->post('submit');
                 if( $formSubmit == 'save' ){
                     $this->add_model->insert_into_db();
                     //loading success view
                     redirect('speed/insert_to_db');
                    }
             }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch your all devices data and brand data from controller then pass it in view.

In view you have to print all devices and band in foreach loop and create options.

For Example:

**In Cotroller:**

```
$this->load->model('add_model');
$data['devices']=$this->add_model->all_devices();
$data['brand']=$this->add_model->all_brands();
$this->load->view('your view for insert this data');
```

**In Model:**

```
function all_devices()
{
   code for fetch all devices
}
function all_brand()
{
   code for fetch all brands
}
```

**In view :**

```
Device Type:<select name="deviceType" >
               <? foreach ($devices as $d) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $d['device_id']?>"><?php echo $d['device_name']?></option>
                <? }?>
          </select><br/>
Brand:<select name="brand" >
                <? foreach($brands as $b) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $b['brand_id']?>"><?php echo $b['brand_name']?></option>
                <? }?>
          </select><br/>
```

Hope this will Help you.

Comment: You mean the code to fetch the all data of devices and brands?

Comment: i edited my code which i can print it in my view except in select box you can see it and help please

Comment: add ( ) in loop in view page.

Device Type:<select name="deviceType" >
               <? foreach ($devices as $d) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $d['device_id']?>"><?php echo $d['device_name']?></option>
                <? }?>
          </select><br/>


Can you get Your Output ?

Comment: no,undefined variable:d filename :pages/home.php line11

Comment: OK, SORRY it was my mistake i have edited my code. In brand option i have write $d in spite of $b.


<option value="<?php echo $b['brand_id']?>"><?php echo $b['brand_name']?></option>

Comment: sorry,i need to load only brand option first for test then complete my app